# How to upload to s3 from ec2 log files through lambda & boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I want to upload only Ec2 log files through lambda.

I have code for this

```
import json
import os
import datetime as dt
import boto3
import socket

region = 'ap-northeast-2'
instances = []
ec2_r = boto3.resource('ec2')
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

for instance in ec2_r.instances.all():
    for tag in instance.tags:
        if tag['Key'] == 'Log-Archive':
            if tag['Value'] == 'True':
                instances.append(instance.id)
             
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")   
    dir_path = "/log"
    bucket = 'mybucket'
    x = dt.datetime.now()
    date = x.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    def log(in_path):
        for (dir_path, dir, files) in os.walk(in_path):
            for file in files:
                if date in file:
                    yield os.path.join(dir_path, file)
                    
    for file_name in log(dir_path):
        key = socket.gethostname() + '/' + file_name
        res = s3.upload_file(file_name, bucket, key)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
    }
```

When I tested this code it returned 200 code. but nothing in my bucket.
And I tested this code on my local ec2 without lambda code, and It works

```
33

Response
{
  "statusCode": 200
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 39f63d4f-e154-48b8-9fb3-51b98f927a30 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 39f63d4f-e154-48b8-9fb3-51b98f927a30
REPORT RequestId: 39f63d4f-e154-48b8-9fb3-51b98f927a30  Duration: 51.61 ms  Billed Duration: 52 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 89 MB

Request ID
39f63d4f-e154-48b8-9fb3-51b98f927a30
```

Can I take some advices? thanks for all answers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "EC2 log files"? Are you referring to files that are stored on an Amazon EC2 instance? It would be difficult for an AWS Lambda function to access files on an EC2 instance. It is typically easier for code running on the EC2 instance to copy files directly to Amazon S3. Alternatively, you could [Collect metrics and logs from Amazon EC2 instances and on-premises servers with the CloudWatch agent - Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html) or use AWS Systems Manager to run scripts that copy the data to S3.

Comment: Yes I mean my application logs in ec2. Thanks. If nothing way then I will try to AWS Systems Manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Lambda will be running in a serverless compute environment, not in your EC2. That means the `log` directory that you are traversing is in the serverless Lambda environment, not the `log` directory in your EC2 instance. My guess is, the Lambda `log` directory contains no log files. Hence, the code ran successfully without uploading anything to S3.

My suggestion is to keep this python as a local script in the instance. Then, as you have already indicated, you can use AWS SSM to trigger this script.

Comment: Thank you. I will find way through ur advice.

Answer (score 0):

you probably miss to install in your ec2 the cloudwatch agent.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html
Furthermore, there is no need to "move" log between services, because AWS provide automatic logging for everything, with Cloudwatch and Cloudtrail services